# Better way to access nested attributes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, arguments

I have this function in which I want to access nested attributes from passed arguments inside the function.

```js
var objectsArr = [
  {nestedobj:{property:'1'}},
  {nestedobj:{property:'3'}},
  {nestedobj:{property:'2'}},
  {nestedobj:{property:'4'}}
];

function sortObjectsArr(objectsArray) {
  if (arguments.length == 2) {
    objectsArray.sort((a,b) => a[arguments[1]] - b[arguments[1]]);
  }

  if (arguments.length == 3) {
    objectsArray.sort((a,b) => a[arguments[1]][arguments[2]] - b[arguments[1]][arguments[2]]);
  }

  if (arguments.length == 4) {
    objectsArray.sort((a,b) => a[arguments[1]][arguments[2]][arguments[3]] - b[arguments[1]][arguments[2]][arguments[3]]);
  }  
  //and so on and so forth
}


sortObjectsArr(objectsArr, 'nestedobj', 'property');

console.log(objectsArr);
```

Is there a nicer way to access the attributes from the object? rather than `[arguments[1]][arguments[2]][arguments[3]]....` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I would first take the other args as a rest parameter instead of using the arguments array.
Then i wold define a small helper function.

```js
function sortObjectsArr(objectsArray, ...path) {
  objectsArray.sort((a, b) => getFromPath(a, path) - getFromPath(b, path))
}

function getFromPath(obj, path) {
  let r = obj;
  path.forEach(key => { r = r[key]})
  return r
}

let objectsArr = [
  {nestedobj:{property:'1'}},
  {nestedobj:{property:'3'}},
  {nestedobj:{property:'2'}},
  {nestedobj:{property:'4'}}
]; 

sortObjectsArr(objectsArr, 'nestedobj', 'property'); 
console.log(objectsArr);
```

Finally: avoid using `var`, use let instead, its old and behaves weirdly (in ways you wouldnt expect). But explaining that is outside of this answer, you can google it.

EDIT: if you want to be really cool you can use the reduce function:

```js
function getFromPath(obj, path) {
     return path.reduce((o, key) => o[key], obj)
}
```

If this is more readable you need to decide for yourself.